# Hubble - specific date

Tags: sql, date

How to write a command in Hubble to extract data only from a specific date?

e.g.
products sold only on 20 October 2021

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I write a command "WHERE product_sold_date = '2021-10-20'" but I get also other dates in the result table not only this date.